# Скачивание pdf файла через requests

Tags: python, парсер, requests, pdf

Я хочу скачать ряд .pdf файлов с сайта, использую обычный код на requests. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Пробовал добавлять заголовки и cookies. Единственное решение - скачивать через selenium?

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'ras.arbitr.ru',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://ras.arbitr.ru',
    'referer': 'https://ras.arbitr.ru/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Opera GX";v="100"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/100.0.0.0 (Edition Yx GX)',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

url = 'https://ras.arbitr.ru/Document/Pdf/914dfd25-2551-48c2-8c51-1212a48d462a/9a385df4-efcf-460e-a6fc-f726180d55d4/А63-15673-2022__20231122.pdf?isAddStamp=True'
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('1.pdf', 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
else:
    print(response.reason)
```

Comment: Если сохранить в html файл видно, что оно требует ввода капчи

Answer (score 0):

В вашем запросе отсутствует token, hash. Беглый осмотр вроде говорит, что запрос должен быть POST и с датой.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "датой"? дата вроде 2023.08.07 или "данные"?

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что post запрос используется для отправки данных, а здесь мы вроде их получаем?

Comment: https://ras.arbitr.ru/Document/Pdf/914dfd25-2551-48c2-8c51-1212a48d462a/9a385df4-efcf-460e-a6fc-f726180d55d4/А63-15673-2022__20231122.pdf?isAddStamp=True
Откройте в вашем браузере и посмотрите как вы получаете информацию там все есть. И то что это Post запрос. Post потому что вы с ссылкой передаете информацию (дата - токен и hash). Их требуется забирать при первой авторизации или заходе на сайт.

Comment: Вы в любом случае получаете данные. И в POST и в GET.